# Update statement based on select SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-update, updates

I have select which is works perfectly.

```
update ClientS set StatusID=4
where ClientID= (select P.ClientID
   ,LastName+' '+FirstName as Name 
   ,Address
   ,max(p.PickupDate)as 'Last Pickup'
   ,DATEDIFF(month,max(p.PickupDate),GETDATE())as'last pickup was months ago'
from Pickup P
join Clients C on P.ClientID= C.ClientID
where WIC=0 and C.StatusID = 1 or WIC=0 and C.StatusID = 2
group by p.clientid, lastname + ' ' + firstname,address
order by 4)
```

I need update statement based on one `last pickup was months ago` in this select. I need update clients `StatusID` in `Clients` table and set it to 4 only for those clients in this select who have last pickup more than 2 months ago.
so far I have this

```
create procedure pr_UpdateStatusHwoPickupMoreThanTwoM 
AS
update ClientS set StatusID=4
where ClientID= (select P.ClientID
   ,LastName+' '+FirstName as Name 
   ,Address
   ,max(p.PickupDate)as 'Last Pickup'
   ,DATEDIFF(month,max(p.PickupDate),GETDATE())as'last pickup was months ago'
from Pickup P
join Clients C on P.ClientID= C.ClientID
where WIC=0 and C.StatusID = 1 or WIC=0 and C.StatusID = 2
group by p.clientid, lastname + ' ' + firstname,address
order by 4)
```

I know it is not right, i need somehow specify that last pickup was more than 2 months ago but cannot figured it out how to and change `StatusID` only for those `ClientID`. Any Ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
update C
set StatusID=4
from (SELECT P.ClientID, MAX(p.PickupDate) MaxPickupDate
      FROM @Pickup P
      group by P.Clientid) P
     join @Clients C on P.ClientID= C.ClientID
where C.WIC=0 and C.StatusID in (1, 2)
      AND P.MaxPickupDate<DATEADD(month,-2,GETDATE())
```

Also, you have mistake here

```
where WIC=0 and C.StatusID = 1 or WIC=0 and C.StatusID = 2
```

this condition will be true for any row with WIC=0, you can correct it this way

```
WHERE WIC=0 AND C.StatusID in (1,2)
```

Comment: doesnt like group by Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.

Comment: @AndreyIvanov I updated the answer. Just forgot that `UPDATE FROM` doesn't allow `GROUP BY`.

Comment: it set all clients as inactive StatusID 4, good i did it on test table not on real table in db :)

Comment: @Iror Thanx! problem was in WHERE WIC=0 AND C.StatusID in (1,2) I change it to WHERE C.StatusID in (1,2) and WIC=0 . And it start working as it must be! Spasibo

Comment: @AndreyIvanov Pozhaluysta :) although I didn't get how changing `WHERE WIC=0 AND C.StatusID in (1,2)` to `WHERE C.StatusID in (1,2) and WIC=0` could help you because they are the same.

Comment: I have no Idea but it works and change Status only for those who did not do pickup more than 2 months :) maybe it is SQL Magic :)

Comment: @AndreyIvanov Experience has taught me that there is no magic except we do :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

For SQL SERVER

```
update ClientS set StatusID=4
where ClientID= (select P.ClientID
from Pickup P
join Clients C on P.ClientID= C.ClientID
where WIC=0 and C.StatusID = 1 or WIC=0 and C.StatusID = 2
group by p.clientid 
having max(p.PickupDate) < DATEADD(month,-2,GETDATE()));
```

Your inner query is returning multiple columns for 1 row which you are comparing with only clientId that iswhy you are not getting desired results.

Comment: throwing error Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

Comment: Which version of sqlserver you are using ?

Comment: it is sql express r2 2008 SP2

Comment: Error change by still doesnot work Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Comment: Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int. In my select i already have calculated months it is last column.

Comment: I think it doesn't like DATEDIFF(month,-2,GETDATE())); in last line of yours statement

Comment: Change datediff to dateadd, datediff returns int that is why the error was coming for comparing int with date. Check the edit